# Why isn't win32api.SendMessage able to perfom mouse clicks in some applications

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I'm on Windows OS and I'm trying to perform clicks on background (inactive) applications without bringing them to the front.
I've been successful in doing in in Microsoft Paint (painting a dot on a minimised paint instance) but for some reason this doesn't seem to work on a Java based application (RuneLite.exe) which I'm writing this program for.

Some additional information:

- Paint has a lot of child windows and performing the click only seems to work when I execute it on a specific child window (class: Afx:00007FF758890000:8) this is the most inner window.
- The RuneLite window structure is as follows:

  - RuneLite (class: SunAwtFrame)

    - unknown (class: SunAwtCanvas)

      - unknown (class SunAwtCanvas)
- I've tried using the handle of all 3 of the above windows but none seem to work
- The code is able to find the handle of the window and it is correct (checked with Spy++)
- The window blinks orange in the taskbar after running the code so some event must have been fired
- I have determined the coordinates by screenshotting the window and using paint to find coordinates of a specific location. (If there is a better way of doing this, please let me know)

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

amount = 2
handles = []

def start_apps():
    for i in range(amount):
        a = Application()
        a.start("D:\\Users\\Arno\\AppData\\Local\\RuneLite\\RuneLite.exe")
        time.sleep(15)
        handle = a.window().child_window(class_name="SunAwtCanvas", found_index=1).handle # select the most inner window
        handles.append(handle)


def do_click(h, x, y):
    long_position = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)  # simulate the mouse pointer and send it to the specified coordinates
    win32api.SendMessage(h, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, long_position)  # simulate mouse press
    win32api.SendMessage(h, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, long_position)  # Simulate mouse up


start_apps()
print(handles)
time.sleep(20)
for h in handles:
    do_click(h, 450, 290)
```

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96L9x.png)

Does anyone know why this happens and how I could go about fixing it?